# Swift Codable: how to "pass through" a json sub-object unanalysed

Tags: swift, codable

For complicated reasons I find myself working against the grain of `Codable`: when decoding a json object I want to preserve the sub-object under the key `extra` "just as json", stored as a `[String: Any]` dictionary, but `[String: Any]` is (of course) not `Decodable`. Is there any way to do this?

The first answer is of course "don't". To which my response is "I need to": I need to make *two* `Codable` passes over the data, in which the first decodes a list of heterogeneous objects (which each have a key `name`) while the second pass uses a dictionary keyed on those `name` values and is properly type-safe. The first pass cannot be type-safe because it's operating on a heterogenous list, but it needs to preserve all the data that the second pass will work with. Thankfully all the heterogenous data is hidden under that `extra` key, but still I don't see how to do it.

(There will very likely be a followup question about _en_coding the same things, so if you happen to have insight feel free to mention it.)

Comment: Can you have two sets of your `Codable` struct hierarchy, one without the `extra` and one with `extra` but other stuff removed and then use one for the first decoding and the other for the second decoding? Just thinking out loud here, I have never tried anything like this myself.

Comment: did you try [String:AnyHashable] type?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think the second pass needs to work with the _output_ of the first, so I don't think I can skip `extra` entirely. Thanks for the suggestion though, it's rolling around in my head and might still spark a new insight.

Comment: @Rishabh not `Codable` (for the usual reason related to type erasure or heterogeneity: encoding is fine but when decoding there's no way to tell what to put into the `AnyHashable`)

Comment: Check this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80288 it looks like a similar issue and there is an answer there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Swift Forums post](https://forums.swift.org/t/using-unsafe-pointers-to-manipulate-a-json-encoder/11013/6) appears to provide a solution. It starts thusly:

```
public enum JSON : Codable {
    case null
    case number(NSNumber)
    case string(String)
    case array([JSON])
    case dictionary([String : JSON])
    // ...
```

The idea is to make an explicit `JSON` enum type, which is `Codable`, directly encoding the json structure (`case string(String); case array([JSON]);` etc). The unanalysed sub-object gets strongly-typed to `JSON` and can be encoded/decoded via `Codable`, and (as a bonus) can also be analysed with "just Swift" (switch on the case and do stuff) if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Custom Dictionary `Decodable` which decodes and stores the values in an `Dictionary` and then use this type for the key in which you want to store raw dictionary.

Here is the Decodable:

```
struct DictionaryDecodable: Decodable {

    let dictionary : [String: Any]

    private struct Key : CodingKey {

        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
        var dict = [String: Any]()
        for key in con.allKeys {
            if let value = try? con.decode(String.self, forKey:key) {
                dict[key.stringValue] = value
            } else if let value = try? con.decode(Int.self, forKey:key) {
                dict[key.stringValue] = value
            } else if let value = try? con.decode(Double.self, forKey:key) {
                dict[key.stringValue] = value
            } else if let value = try? con.decode(Bool.self, forKey:key) {
                dict[key.stringValue] = value
            } else if let data = try? con.decode(DictionaryDecodable.self, forKey:key)  {
                dict[key.stringValue] = data.dictionary
            }

        }
        self.dictionary = dict
    }
}
```

Now you can use this struct to decode dictionary like this:

```
struct Test: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let data: [String: Any]

    enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        data = try container.decode(DictionaryDecodable.self, forKey: .data).dictionary // Here use DictionaryDecodable
    }
}
```

Let's test:

```
let data = """
{
    "name": "name",
    "data": {
        "string": "rt",
        "bool": true,
        "float": 1.12,
        "int": 1,
        "dict": {
            "test": "String"
        }
    }
}
"""

let s = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: data.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(s.name)
print(s.data)
```

Here's the output:

```
name
["bool": true, "string": "rt", "int": 1, "float": 1.12, "dict": ["test": "String"]]
```

Comment: You could get rid of the manually written `init` for `Test ` if you declare the property as `DictionaryDecodable`. Also adding `[Bool`], `[String]`, etc, to the list of attempted decodings would help.

Comment: Yes we can do that, then at every access point you have to use `.dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

The closest I got was the following Playgrounds code:

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    let bar: [String: Any]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bar
    }

    init(bar: [String: Any]) {
        self.bar = bar
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let barString = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .bar)
        let barData = Data(barString.utf8)
        let json: [String: Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: barData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
        bar = json
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let barData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bar, options: .sortedKeys)
        let barString = String(decoding: barData, as: UTF8.self)
        try container.encode(barString, forKey: .bar)
    }
}

let foo = Foo(bar: ["someInt": 1])
let fooData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(foo)
print(String(decoding: fooData, as: UTF8.self))
print(String(decoding: fooData, as: UTF8.self).replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\"", with: "\""))

let decodedFoo = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: fooData)
print(decodedFoo)
```

The above prints:

```
{"bar":"{\"someInt\":1}"}
{"bar":"{"someInt":1}"}
Foo(bar: ["someInt": 1])
```

It's not perfect yet, because it escapes the `"` in the resulting JSON string, so that will probably break something in there. The additional string replacement pass is probably not something that is enjoyable.

Comment: This approach can probably be made to work (with some tweaking for the escaping) for round-tripping Swift->JSON->Swift, but not for decoding server-produced JSON: the encoded form necessarily wraps bar's sub-object in a string, which the server will not do. If round-tripping is the only requirement, simply encoding/decoding `bar` as `Data` via `JSONSerialization` is probably simpler.